# Validar se idade da data é menor de 18

Tags: php

Estou tentando verificar se a idade da data informada é menor de 18 sem necessidade de verificação se é maior de 18, mas estranhamente não funcionada. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
$DataNascimento = '2007/09/02';

// VERIFICANDO SE USUÁRIO TEM +18
$VerificaIdade = explode('/', $DataNascimento);
$Ano = $VerificaIdade[0];
$Mes = $VerificaIdade[1];
$Dia = $VerificaIdade[2];

// UNIX timestamp
$Nascimento = mktime(0, 0, 0, $Dia, $Mes, $Ano);

// fetch the current date (minus 18 years)
$Verifica['Dia'] = date('d');
$Verifica['Mes'] = date('m');
$Verifica['Ano'] = date('Y') - 18;

// Timestamp
$Hoje = mktime(0, 0, 0, $Verifica['Dia'], $Verifica['Mes'], $Verifica['Ano']);

if ($Nascimento < $Hoje) {
    // Não preciso desse IF;
} else {
    echo 'Usuário Menor de 18 anos';
}
```

Comment: Se não precisa do `if`, basta inverter a condição para `if ($Nascimento >= $Hoje) { echo 'Usuário Menor de 18 anos'; }` :-)

Comment: Olá @hkotsubo, já tinha feito isso, valeu pela resposta.